# rsna-tkip vs rsna-ccmp

Tags: networking, wap

In networking, What Is the difference between RSNA-TKIP and RSNA-CCMP?

will a device set to associate with one be able to associate with the other one?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have been reading through WiFi Specs. So here is my understanding ->

TKIP is used in RC4 algorithm and used by WPA(1), TKIP is prone to attacks.
CCMP is used in AES algorithm and used by WPA2, CCMP is less prone to attacks and provides better security than TKIP.

Now TKIP can be implemented in driver/firmware, but for CCMP it requires new hardware. This limits existing (WEP based) device to upgrade only to WPA.

So, if a device does not have the capability to use WPA2, it cannot connect to the WPA2(CCMP-PSK/CCMP-802.1X) AP. Most device should support WPA(TKIP-PSK/TKIP-802.1X).

Hope this helps.